# kustomize doesn't inject labels on generated configmaps

Tags: kustomize

I've created this kustomize structure:

```
kustomize
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── kustomizeconfig
│   │   ├── generators
│   │   │   ├── mongos-configuration-file-configmap-generator.yaml
│   │   │   ├── mongos-keyfile-script-configmap-generator.yaml
│   │   │   └── secret-generator.yaml
│   │   └── transformers
│   │       └── labels-transformer.yaml
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   └── scripts
│       └── mongodb-keyfile-script.sh
├── components
│   ├── common-labels
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── kustomizeconfig
│   │       └── transformers
│   │           └── labels-transformer.yaml
...
```

Into `components/common-labels/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

transformers:
  - kustomizeconfig/transformers/labels-transformer.yaml
```

Into `components/common-labels/kustomizeconfig/transformers/labels-transformer.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: builtin
kind: LabelTransformer
metadata:
  name: notImportantHere
labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
fieldSpecs:
- path: metadata/labels
  create: true
```

However, kustomize is only injecting labels on `service` and `deployment` resources. It's ignoring generated `compigmaps`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongos-configuration-file
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mongodb-keyfile-script.sh: "#!/bin/sh\n\n# Retrieve the value of the MONGODB_KEYFILE
    environment variable\nkeyfile_content=$MONGODB_KEYFILE\n\nif [ -n \"$keyfile_content\"
    ]; then\n\t# Write the content to the file\n\techo \"$keyfile_content\" >/mongodb/keyfile\n\techo
    \"Keyfile content written to /mongodb/keyfile\"\n\n\t# Set permissions mode to
    600\n\tchmod 600 /mongodb/keyfile\n\techo \"Permissions set to 600 for /mongodb/keyfile\"\nelse\n\techo
    \"MONGODB_KEYFILE environment variable not found.\"\nfi\n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongos-keyfile-script
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
  name: mongos
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 27017
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongos
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
  name: mongos
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - mongos
        - --config
        - /config/mongos.conf
        image: mongo
        name: mongos
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config
          name: config-volume
        - mountPath: /mongodb
          name: mongodb-volume
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - /scripts/mongodb-keyfile-script.sh
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_KEYFILE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: sharedKey
              name: mongos
        image: mongo
        name: chmod
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /scripts
          name: scripts-volume
        - mountPath: /mongodb
          name: mongodb-volume
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: mongos-keyfile-script
        name: scripts-volume
      - configMap:
          name: mongos-configuration-file
        name: config-volume
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: mongodb-volume
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the ConfigMap defined? This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- a set of manifests and one or more `kustomization.yaml` files that we can use to reproduce the problem.